# How to add the value of textboxes and display the result in a texbox in c# windows form

Tags: c#

can you help me here..
I have a 5 textbox how will you automatically get the sum of those textbox who has a value and display it to textboxtotal. Like when you enter a number in textbox1 the value displays on the textboxtotal and when you enter a value on another textbox it automatically get the sum and so on.... and when you clear the value you entered on one textbox the textboxtotal will be updated..

Hope you can help me

Comment: you can't automatically get anything you need to write code that will do the `summation` do a `google search` on `Key Press Events` I hate to be rude but `Can you Code...?` this is not a free coding site what have you even tried on your own..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this for adding values -

```
    public void AddValues()
    {
        int val1, val2, val3, val4, val5;

        int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out val1);
        int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out val2);
        int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out val3);
        int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out val4);
        int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out val5);

        textboxtotal.Text = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5).ToString();
    }
```

Now, for other part of your question, just call `AddValues()` in `TextChanged` event of your textboxes.

Comment: You would need "out" in those TryParse calls.

Comment: oops! sorry missed it... Updated !!

Comment: this is not a really good answer also Prateek Singh, you are only attempting to answer half of the OP's question what about clearing the text.. it would have been better if you would let the OP attempt some code on his own first opposed to giving an answer that the op can't understand to begin with

Comment: @Prateek Singh & Clay Fowler. It works. Thanks for the help, appreciate it...  &DJ KRAZE I'm just a beginner in coding.

Answer (score 1):

Place all your input textboxses (WITHOUT result textbox) into some container component like panel or groupbox. set to all input textboxses THE SAME Leave handler, with code, like below:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GroupBox parent = (((TextBox) sender).Parent as GroupBox);
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                string tbContent = (textBox).Text;
                int tbNumValue;
                if(int.TryParse(tbContent, out tbNumValue))
                {
                    sum += tbNumValue;
                }
            }
        }

        tbResult.Text = sum == 0 ? string.Empty : sum.ToString();
    }
```