# Show result of calculation in textbox

Tags: c#

Hello can somebody tell me how i can Display the result of d in a TextBox?

```
private void Zaehnezahl_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  double a = 0;
  double b = 0;
  double c = 0;
  double d = 0;


  if (Double.TryParse(Modul.Text, out a) && Double.TryParse(Zaehnezahl.Text, out b) && Double.TryParse(Schraegungswinkel.Text, out c))

      d = (a * b) / (System.Math.Cos(c * (Math.PI / 180)));
```

Comment: googeling **c# display calculation result in textbox** I get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493448/how-to-add-the-value-of-textboxes-and-display-the-result-in-a-texbox-in-c-sharp) as the first hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TextBox always take a string value and also return a string value. So you have to use ToString() function to convert value of d to string type.

```
txtTextBoxName.Text=d.ToString();
```

Comment: Care to add some explanation

Comment: I just was test your answere and it was working very well. thank you very mutch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .Text property of the TextBox.

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.Text = d;
```

*Use TextBox if you already have one and replace t with your TextBox - As suggested by @UnLucky*

Comment: I'm agree with this point `You can use the .Text property of the TextBox.` But `t` is a new TextBox which is not present in the UI and you forgot to mention that he have to add the TexBox to the UI to make it display.

Comment: @un-lucky - t was just for an example and completeness. I thought the TextBox will already be there. But thanks for pointing that out.. :-)

Comment: Let me add one more thing that, `d` is of type double and you are assigning it as .`Text` which means a conversion from double to string so this code won't work until you add `d.ToString()`

Comment: @the_up_voters : Please care while casting your votes

Comment: @A3006 this code does not compile

Comment: @MongZhu - If you copy only these two lines, it will not compile as it will try to find "d". Paste your code with exception.

Comment: @A3006 unless `d` is of type `string` this code will not compile. I guess you chose `d` because OP used it in the post as the result of the calculation variable and it is of type `double`! You cannot assign a double to the `Text` property. The compiler will tell you: "Cannot implicitly convert double to string"